# how do I update table1 values (select from table2) where table1.email = table2.email

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I have trying to copy some data from one table to another where the email addresses are the same.

For example:

Table 1 has fields:
`email, title, first_name, last_name, (+ others)`

Table 2 has fields:
`email, title, first_name, last_name, modified, (+ others)`

I want to copy the `title`, `first_name`, `last_name` from `table2` to `table1` where `table1.email = table2.email`.

So `table2` holds all the data, which I would like to copy into `table1` where the email in `table1` matches the `FIRST 'most recent (by 'modified')' email found` in `table2` (so the most recent modified `datetime`).

I was trying something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `table1` (title, first_name, last_name)
    SELECT title, first_name, last_name from `table2`
    WHERE table1.email = table2.email

ERROR: Unknown column 'table1.email' in 'where clause'
```

So basically, I need something like this in one statement..

```
SELECT EMAIL as `originalEmail` FROM `table1` 
    SELECT title, first_name, last_name FROM `table2` 
    WHERE table2.email = table1.email
    ORDER BY `modified` desc # Get the most recently modified
    LIMIT 1                  # limit to 1 result (the most recent one)
UPDATE `table1` (title, first_name, last_name) values (*values from above*)
WHERE EMAIL = `originalEmail`
```

---

Edit
 - I would like to `UPDATE` and not `INSERT` a new record.

Comment: Maybe you need to UPDATE?

Comment: Do you wanna update the actual values or insert new values?

Comment: Why are you getting `ERROR: Unknown column 'table1.email' in 'where clause'?` Is email column there in in table1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this query -

```
UPDATE `table1` t1
  JOIN `table2` t2
    ON t1.email = t2.email
SET
  t1.title = t2.title,
  t1.first_name = t2.first_name,
  t1.last_name = t2.last_name
```

---

Query with *most recent* condition for `table2` records -

```
UPDATE `table1` t1
  JOIN (SELECT * FROM `table2` GROUP BY email ORDER BY modified DESC) t2
    ON t1.email = t2.email
SET
  t1.title = t2.title,
  t1.first_name = t2.first_name,
  t1.last_name = t2.last_name
```

Comment: Where is the last modified email condition?

Comment: @RAS I will add new query soon.

Comment: The second query finds most recent data. Try it too.